# Algebra of additive polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field for an odd prime $p$. Consider the ring
$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p(X),Y)$$ of additive (or linearized) polynomials in $Y$ over the rational function field $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$. That is, we are interested in polynomials of the form
$$a_n(X)Y^{p^n} + a_{n-1}(X)Y^{p^{n-1}} + \dots + a_1(X)Y^{p} + a_0(X)Y$$
with $a_j(X) \in \mathbb{F}_p(X)$ for every $0 \leq j \leq n$. Addition is the usual, while multiplication is now function composition, making $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p(X),Y)$ a *non-commutative* ring with unity.

My interest is regarding this non-commutativity of the multiplication in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p(X),Y)$ and its structure as a ring.

> What can we say about the structure of the multiplicative monoid of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p(X),Y)$?
>
> What is the center of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p(X),Y)$? It is clear that the center contains $\mathbb{F}_p Y$, but is that the whole center?

The same questions can be asked of the ring $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p[X],Y)$ of linearized polynomials with coefficients now from the domain $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ instead of the rational function field.

> What can we say about the structure of the multiplicative monoid of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p[X],Y)$?
>
> What is the center of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p[X],Y)$? Again, it is clear that the center contains $\mathbb{F}_p Y$, but is that the whole center?

This is only the surface. Even more interesting is how this multiplication behaves with regard to absolute irreducibility of the polynomials, its roots (in an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$), its splitting fields, etc. But I'll get to those later.

Apologies if the question is broad, and will refine it as I get more familiar with the object . I am interested in all aspects of the structure of the non-commutative multiplication here, so any comprehensive references would be valuable. The ones I googled seem way too sophisticated and abstract (Drinfeld modules and the like) that I don't know where to even begin.

Please feel free to share any interesting facts about the non-commutative ring $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}_p[X],Y)$ (and its multiplicative monoid) that you know of. Thanks.

Comment: Are you even sure composition is a ring operation in this case? Usually it is not. Suppose $p\neq 2$, and then if $p^n(p+p)$ were to be distributive, you'd need $2^{n-1}=1$, and I'm not sure if that's always the case.

Comment: A few remarks (I'm mostly ignorant about this). 1) Calling something a $k$-algebra for a field $k$ often implies that $k$ should be a subset of the center. That is not the case here, right? 2) [Carlitz module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlitz_exponential) is a bit simpler than Drinfeld module (?). Wikipedia recommends D. Goss's book. I own a copy, but never had the time to really delve into it. 3) IIRC later chapters in [Rosen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953359) makes (IIRC) the Carlitz module relatively accessible (and I enjoyed that book immensely anyway).

Comment: @rschwieb: I think the ring operation is the following composition. If $r_1(X,Y)$ and $r_2(X,Y)$ are two additive polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_p(X)[Y]$, then the composition means $(r_1\circ r_2)(X,Y)=r_1(X,r_2(X,Y))$. Because $r_1(X,Y_1+Y_2)=r_1(X,Y_1)+r_1(X,Y_2)$ distributivity follows.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 1) You're right that it isn't an algebra but just a ring. I have edited that, thanks. Do you know of any other similar rings of polynomials over a function field that is a non-commutative algebra? 2) So a Carlitz module is an embedding of the (commutative) ring $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ in a larger non-commutative ring, as I understand it, right? Does that give any information about the center of the larger ring? 3) Thanks, will check out your suggestions. I just hope it doesn't get too abstract. After all, I am interested in a rather simple example ring.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Distribution following because of the Freshman Dream theorem? Maybe that's what I was having trouble seeing. I guess this particular choice of 'linearized' polynomials makes that all work?

Comment: The structure of the *ring* $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right], Y\right)$ is rather well-known: it is isomorphic to the Ore polynomial ring $\mathcal{F} := \mathbb{F}_p\left< F, T \mid FT = T^p F\right>$. This follows from Theorem 3.13 in my [*Do the symmetric functions have
a function-field analogue?*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/schur-ore.pdf), but of course goes back to Ore essentially. The center of this ring $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$, as can be easily seen using the explicit basis (Proposition 3.5).